# How to make error messages configurable in Umbraco 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, umbraco7

I am creating a brand new website in Umbraco 7 as back-end and ASP.NET MVC as code base. 
I am want to add the error messages in Umbraco (CMS) as my web site is multilingual. 
Now the problem is: how do make the error messages configurable? 
I have created a Utilitiy class which will have all the constants defined which will store the error messages.
Following is that class:

```
namespace MCA102.BusinessLogic
{
    public sealed class Utility
    {
        private Utility() { }


        public const string Val1 = /get message from umbraco/
        public const string Val2 = "";

    }
}
```

What should I write after the `val1` declaration?
Which Umbraco classes I should add at the top?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with making error messages configurable? Do you mean multilingual messages? And do you want to get these error messages from umbraco? From the dictionary? Or from document types?

Comment: Basically, I want to store the error messages in umbarco 7 and i want to access them in my Csharp classes, I dont know which 'using' file i should add at the top of the class. What could be the code to access error message. And yes my messages will be in different languages.

Comment: So you want to use an Umbraco documenttype to store error information and retrieve them using C#? Assuming the nodes are published, you could use UmbracoHelper to query your data from the cache. This class is located in Umbraco.Web. If you want to query the database directly you'd use ContentService from Umbraco.Core.Services